# Migrating data from Visual Foxpro using OLEDB - Less number of rows migrated

Tags: oledb, data-migration, visual-foxpro

I am rewriting an application that existed in Foxpro earlier. As a part of this rewrite we also need to migrate all the data from Foxpro to SQL server.

We have built a .NET application for data migration. The application reads data from Foxpro (.dbc file), transforms it, and then load to a SQL server table. We are using VFPOLEDB provider. The process works fine for most of the data. But for some data the extract process does not load all the rows from Foxpro. I cannot see a valid reason for this behavior. For instance if I go to Visual Foxpro and run a sql query it returns me more rows than when I run the same query with OLEDB provider. Why is this difference? I would highly appreciate if someone can provide some insight into it.

Answer (score 0):

Are the rows deleted? If you have SET DELETED ON in VFP deleted rows will also be returned.

Comment: It gives me the right number of rows in VFP (9.0) but using OLEDB from C# code it does not give the correct number of rows. It skips a few rows for no apparent reason.

Comment: Do you know exactly which rows? Have you visually checked them?

Comment: Yes I have. They look just like the other rows with no problem. I even tried changing the data to match with the ones that are working but still couldn't migrate them.

Comment: Have you tried different select statements through the OLEDB driver that try to select one of the missing rows directly?

Answer (score 0):

FoxPro tables are notorious for getting corrupted. What version of VFP are you using to test the tables? Earlier versions of VFP did not complain about corruption but the OBDC driver might skip those rows.

Comment: VFP version 9.0. How can you know which rows are corrupted?

Comment: BTW I am using OLEDB driver not ODBC driver.